# Issues while displaying date in the format 12 Jan 2014 12:10 in PDF report

Tags: excel, date, number-formatting

I have an issue in displaying the date in the format `12 Jan 2012 12:10` ie (dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm) in .pdf viewer. What I have tried is:

I selected the cell and in the format cells section I selected custom and gave the format as:

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM
```

The report has been developed through Excel and when I run the report it runs using a .pdf viewer. In the .pdf viewer it shows the month in a local language, however when I export it to Excel it shows it in English language (preferred by me).

How do I set the locale to English when I select custom format for displaying the value of the cell?

Comment: @pnuts :   Thanks Mate...If u can post this an answer i will accept it..:-) Also can you please explain how it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language code can be added to custom formats. A list of these available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/goglobal/bb964664.aspx). It seems:

```
[$-809]dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM
```

suited OP. '0809' is the Locale ID for English - United Kingdom.